# JS to replace spaces in a string to '+' and pass as Google Search link

Tags: javascript, replace

I am linking a text to Google Search. I have to replace the spaces in text with '+' and pass it in href attribute to link with google search

HTML ->

```
<a href="#" id="afd_gsearch">Search Google</a>
<script>
set("my search string");
</script>
```

JS Code ->

```
function set(text) {
$("#afd_gsearch").attr('href', "https://www..google.com/search?q=" + gsearchquery(text));
}

function gsearchquery(text) {
  var query = text.replace(" ", "+");
  return query;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/srepH/

Comment: What's the purpose of your fiddle? It is completely unrelated. Also, please correct me what?

Comment: What's the question here...

Comment: please help me relate the HTML with JS

Comment: check that "www..google.com" has two "."

Comment: That's not a real question, this is not a code request site

Comment: Note that just replacing the spaces with `+` is not sufficient to properly encode the query string argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this change..
hope this was a help to u

```
function gsearchquery(text) {
  var query = text.split(' ').join('+');
  return query;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean something like url encoding.

```
function gsearchquery(text) {
  var query = encodeURIComponent(text);
  return query;
}
```

Comment: I guess you didn't read the question. Plus, `encodeURIComponent` doesn't encode spaces to plus sign for starters

Comment: @Alexander: yes, encodeURIComponent doesn't encode spaces to plus sign. But i think he needs to pass text with spaces to google. Maybe he thinks that spaces should be replaced with "+"

Comment: Or, you know, just use `encodeURIComponent` directly rather than wrapping it in an additional function. But +1 for `encodeURIComponent` , which is the right thign to do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yes I do agree with you. Using a wrapper here is a little redundant. It's just a quick fix for the OP's function. Putting the logic inside a separate function does have benefits only in case we need more logic than just encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Your current replace statement will replace only the first match.

Replacing your text replace statement with the following should solve it:

```
var query = text.replace(/\s+/g, "+");
```